# Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, utf-8, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app in the Russian language.

Here is my `AlertMessage` class with only one method and one Russian word within:

```
public class AlertMessage {

public static boolean isYes (Context context, String header, String message){
    final boolean[] isYes = {false};
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(header)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton("Да",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            isYes[0] =  true;

                        }
                    }).create().show();
    return isYes[0];
}
}
```

And  I call it from the `MainActivity`:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if(AlertMessage.isYes(this,"Выход","Вы уверены, что хотите выйти из аккаунта?"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        App.super.onBackPressed();
        Log.i("App", "Exit");
        finish();
    }
}
```

Everything work fine except one Russian word in `AlertMessage` class.
It is unreadable. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by unreadable? It is not displayed at all? Does it display the wrong characters? Are you talking about the header, the text or the button text?

Comment: @TimoSta I'm talking about word in `AlertMessage`. it is in wrong encoding, that's why it's unreadable

Comment: externalize your string in strings.xml

Answer (score 6):

You could fix it by using strings from resources like `getString(R.string.error_msg)` instead of hardcoded string.